# add this unallocated space to ubuntu partition

Tags: storage, unallocated

I have googled and checked the other solutions in this forum but none seem to work for me.

Here is what it looks like now:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EImrb.jpg)

and here is the result after running 'sudo parted -ls' :

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EImrb.jpg)

trying to extend the storage space for sda1 to include the unallocated of 31.06 GB.

Comment: sorry, but we are unable to help with this less information. On my system sda1 is /boot/efi. And this is a fat files system. So what file system do you try to extend ? I think it is not fair to ask questions with this gap on information while starting a question/answer game to get to your point :-( So please do more effort on stating questions with information on your configuration and what steps you did (some output may help to).

Comment: Please run the command 'sudo parted -ls' and post the output. ("... space minus ell ess") It will help us help you.

Comment: @malo sorry bout that. didnt notice the image was not attached and i m trying to figure how to show the image on the screen.

Comment: @sudodus attached the image 'screenshot2'

Comment: @VivanRaaj Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are running in VirtualBox.

The virtual drive i around 40 GB, but you use only around 9 GB. It seems you have nothing in the extended partition, at least nothing that can be seen by parted. If this is correct, you can remove or move the extended partition.

- Boot the virtual machine from the image, that you used to install Ubuntu, 'Try Ubuntu'
- Start ***gparted*** and use it to edit the partitions.
- I suggest that you move the extended partition so that there will be unallocated space near the root partition **/dev/sda1**.
- The next step is to expand, 'grow' **/dev/sda1**.
- Finally, you can create a swap partition, for example in the moved extended partition.

The following link might help: [GrowIt.pdf](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/GrowIt.pdf)

Comment: I dont quite get your steps. sorry newbie to ubuntu here. :(

for 1st step, is it rebooting from gpart or 'try ubuntu' .. i ve tried the gpart steps but stuck at extending the unallocated space to the main storage space.

Comment: Is it correct that you run this system in VirtualBox? In that case you should reboot the virtual machine from the Ubuntu iso file (which is connected as an emulated DVD disk, or from a real DVD disk, if you have one). gparted is a program in the system, that you run with 'Try Ubuntu'. You find and start gparted via Dash (the button in the top left corner).

Comment: Please continue to ask until we solve the problem :-)

Comment: yes, its ran in virtual box. i only tried to load it under settings -> storage -> controller:IDE  = gparted-live-0.27.. was following the steps from another site but got stuck

Comment: i think i get what u meant above. but i dont have a copy of the ubuntu iso file as i have deleted it long time ago. if i download a newer version of ubuntu, would it still work?

Comment: Yes, and it should work with a dedicated live system with gparted too. The important thing is to boot from another drive (not the one you want to change).

Comment: yes its working now :)